# Two microphone simultaneous input in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, microphone

I am creating a project but I am having some issues , the project consists in 2 persons screaming on two microphones, and filling a bar with that scream.
The problem is how can flash work with these two inputs simultaneous,this is the code.

```
import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.media.Microphone
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(500);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onMicActivity);
myTimer.start();

var deviceArray:Array = Microphone.names;
var micaux = 0;
var micaux2 = 0;
trace("Available sound input devices:");

for (var i:int = 0; i < deviceArray.length; i++)
{
    trace(" " + deviceArray[i]+ " " + i);
}

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
var mic2:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(1);
trace("mic1 "+mic.name);
trace("mic2 "+mic2.name);
mic.gain = 60;
mic.rate = 11;
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic.setLoopBack(true);
mic.setSilenceLevel(5, 1000);
mic2.gain = 60;
mic2.rate = 11;
mic2.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic2.setLoopBack(true);
mic2.setSilenceLevel(5, 1000);

function onMicActivity(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //trace("activating="  + ", activityLevel=" +  
    // mic.activityLevel);
    if (mic.activityLevel > 3) {
    micaux = micaux + mic.activityLevel;
    }
    if (mic2.activityLevel >3){


    micaux2 = micaux2 + mic2.activityLevel; }
    trace("mic1 " +mic.activityLevel);
    trace("mic 2" +mic2.activityLevel);
    if (micaux>0){
        soundbox.text = String(micaux);
        healthBar.barColor.x +=  mic.activityLevel / 50;
        healthBar.barColor.scaleX +=  mic.activityLevel / 50;}
    if (micaux2>0){ 
        soundbox2.text = String(micaux2);
        healthBar2.barColor.x +=  mic2.activityLevel / 50;
        healthBar2.barColor.scaleX +=  mic2.activityLevel / 50;
    }
```

Soundbox is where appears the score of the user, and healthbar.barcolor is the bar being filled with that score, when i run this code it appear all ok, but only 1 microphone works when i open the settings of that swf the two work ok :\

Hardware is being connected thru two different usb ports.

NETSTREAM didn't solved

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the input from the two mics coming in clearly?

Comment: yes, it's all being received clearly.

Comment: +1 One of my short term goals is to build a game/app that parents get annoyed by when their children are playing it. With all that screaming, you've got a sure winner on your hands :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you cannot enable the microphone loopback for more than one microphone at a time. My experience is that the the last microphone you do `setLoopBack(true)` with is the one that is capturing audio.

One solution is to instead add a listener for `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`. This is the event you would use if you wanted to capture the audio and do something with it. Using this event, you can listen for data from multiple microphones. I've built a "camera/microphone" wizard this that showed activity level from multiple microphones at the same time. The only drawback is that unlike using `setLoopBack(true)`, it doesn't play the audio back to you. But since you are getting the `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`, you could construct a sound object and play that back to the user if you really needed to.

So instead of enabling loopback mode and using a `Timer` to query the activity level for each mic, add listeners for `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`:

```
mic1.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);
mic2.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData);

function onSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    var mic:Microphone = event.target as Microphone;
    trace("activity from: " + mic.name + " level: " + mic.activityLevel);
}
```

This actually works better than using a `Timer`, in the sense that if your timer is running every 500 milliseconds, it may miss occasions when the user is speaking. If the timer fires when the user isn't saying anything, no sound is detected. The `SampleDataEvent` method doesn't have that problem.

References:
[Capturing Sound Output](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html) -- note the section titled "Detecting Microphone Activity", and in particular the "Note:" about the 3 different ways you can detect activity: by using setLoopBack(true), adding a listener for `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`, and by attaching the mic to a `NetStream`. This page also shows how could create a `Sound` object from the samples.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting the `SampleDataEvent` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue several years ago, so I would share my solution.
Embed two flash projections (swfs) on you page then make them communicate through html.
You can then control both swf and get the steams infos shared.
I hope this help.